# WPF ListView Item Data Validation

Tags: wpf, validation, inotifydataerrorinfo

I need to have connection string list which user will append/edit periodically.
So I customized list view which is data bind to a observable collection.

```
<ListView x:Name="DGV_Env" Margin="5" FontSize="11" FontStyle="Italic" ItemsSource="{Binding Environments}" Background="White"
                                       HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionMode="Single"  >    
        <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">           
            <Style.Triggers>                
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="CadetBlue" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ValidationAdornerSite"  Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"/>          
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="PasswordBox">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ValidationAdornerSite"  Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="GV_Env_Column" AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridView.ColumnHeaderContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu FontSize="12" Foreground="Black" />
            </GridView.ColumnHeaderContextMenu>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Slno"  >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Slno}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  FontSize="12" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>           
            <GridViewColumn Header="Server">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Margin="-2,0,-2,0"   BorderThickness="0"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  FontSize="12"  Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Tag="Server">
                            <TextBox.Text>
                                <Binding   Mode="TwoWay" Path="Server" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" >
                                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                        <local:NonEmptyStringValidator ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" ValidationStep="RawProposedValue" />
                                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                </Binding>
                            </TextBox.Text>
                        </TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Database">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Margin="-2,0,-2,0"    BorderThickness="0"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  FontSize="12" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Tag="Database">
                            <TextBox.Text>
                                <Binding   Mode="TwoWay" Path="Database" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" >
                                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                        <local:NonEmptyStringValidator ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" ValidationStep="RawProposedValue" />
                                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                </Binding>
                            </TextBox.Text>
                        </TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="UserID">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Margin="-2,0,-2,0"   BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Tag="User ID">
                            <TextBox.Text>
                                <Binding   Mode="TwoWay" Path="UserId" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" >
                                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                        <local:NonEmptyStringValidator ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" ValidationStep="RawProposedValue" />
                                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                </Binding>
                            </TextBox.Text>
                        </TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Password">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White"  Margin="-2,0,-2,0" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName= ENV_Password}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                                
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />                              
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <PasswordBox Tag="" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="ENV_Password">                                
                                <PasswordBox.Style>

                                </PasswordBox.Style>
                            </PasswordBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I have added Binding.ValidationRules which highlights the fields when its empty. 
Now I have to add validations to validate the connection strings and if any of its fails should be highlighted to user to change the credentials or any connection string parameters. I tried using INotifyDataErrorInfo but couldn't succeed or don't know how to use it properly. It highlights the whole list view as a border and remains the same for the valid connection string too.

I need to highlight to the user which are valid or invalid connection strings in UI and not highlight the whole list view or throw any message boxes. The validation should happen in background and not by any other events (like button click, etc.). How could be this properly achieved.

Comment: "I tried using INotifyDataErrorInfo...". Please post the code you have tried with then.

Comment: It's each item in the collection needs to implement inotifydataerrorinfo. Whatever class a single Environment is. Maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the simplest way to implement binding validations is by throwing exceptions from the setters of your property and then implementing [ValidatesOnExceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validatesonexceptions(v=vs.110).aspx) in your XAML bindings.

I don't know how your `ConnectionString` is handled or built based on your code, but this should lead you in the right direction if you decide this method works for you. In the below example I build my `ConnectionString` in my model (I am assuming you've already implemented `iNotifyPropertyChanged` and understand how it works). The below setter will throw a `FormatException` if the string is empty.

```
 private string connectionString;
 public string ConnectionString
 {
        get { return connectionString; }
        set
        {
            if (connectionString != value)
            {
                //Validate String
                if (value == "") 
                { 
                   throw new FormatException("Connection string cannot be empty");
                }    
                connectionString = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ConnectionString");                       
            }
        }
    }
```

Now lets assume you bound the above connection string to a `TextBox`, but need it to validate when the user deletes the current string and leaves it empty.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ConnectionString, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"/>
```

When the user leaves the TextBox, it will highlight like you want, because ValidatesOnExceptions is set. IMO this solution is very simple and requires little code.

Last thing to note is that in this example, if you passed an empty string in code instead of a UIElement binding, the exception will break the program. Based on your example, I'm not sure exactly what you are planning, but if the strings are only updated through UIElement bindings, you should be fine.